# I get an error in receving data from a fake API for a react-recdux project,

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning using from React-Redux for getting data from a fake API. But I get this error:

`JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

please in the project scroll down to see the above error.

And this error is in console:

`Uncaught Error: Cannot add node 1 because a node with that id is already in the Store.`

I don't know where are my json data. Can anyone help me about Where is the source of the error and this error for what?

Project's code: https://codesandbox.io/s/complete-redux-forked-1qbtvk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in my code. I had not used `worker` for communication with the server.

Previous code:

```
  store.dispatch(fetchUsers());

  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
}
```

The same code after editing:

```
import { worker } from "./api/server";

async function main() {
  await worker.start({ onUnhandledRequest: "bypass" });
  store.dispatch(fetchUsers());

  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
}

main();
```

Also, another wrong was a syntax error(in PostsList.js):

```
  <p className="post-content">{post.content.subString(0, 100)}</p>
```

`subString` was wrong. I edited that to: `substring`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your client.js file which it seems you get the invalid json data
I've tried JSON.stringify instead of json() for valid format and your fake data appeared.
but theres also some warning and error in case of rendering empty or undefined data that you have to fix them.

```
data = JSON.stringify(response)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean that in client.js be `data = await JSON.stringify(response)'? But in this case, it says `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)` and this error `post.content is undefined`. Please see it that is completed of that in redux.js and there it works. Just added some extra properties. But client.js is the same in both:https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux-essentials-example-app/tree/checkpoint-3-postRequests/?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js

Comment: I saw your codes again, glad it works, and you added some changes in your postSlice.js , that time I found the problem in client.js because the data format seemed invalid json and yes by your recent changes your old codes in client.js is right. just wanted to show your content by changing to valid format and I'm glad you fix it

Comment: Thanks again, of course, it still is not my changes. It's the last version of that(completed) on redux.js(https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic). Right now, my code is the same as in my question. But about new properties, I think they don't have a effect for fixing the error. Because they're about `updating` and `added users` and not about the initial loading of posts. So, I still don't understand the reason for the error.